# Moving DbContext to a different project than startup

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to make a WPF desktop application that communicates with a database through EntityFramework. I've separated my solution into several projects: DTO, DAL, Service and WPFApp. I've set up my database context and repositories in the DAL project and I'm using the WPFApp as startup. Because of this, I'm getting an error when trying to add objects to my db: 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.'

Do I have to set up my DbContext and ConnectionString in the Startup Project or is there another way to make this work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure startup project is not the issue. It looks more like invalid  or empty connection string. Can you query your database?
And to answer your question. No your DB context don't have to be in startup project.

Comment: The DbContext should no be defined in the App.config of the running executable (.exe) but the configuration string should.

Comment: I've moved the entity framework packages to my startup project and added the connection string there as well as in the DAL project where I have my DbContext. I couldn't think of a way to only reference EF once, but it works perfectly fine like this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an entity framework database first model in a project there's a checkbox on the connection screen and it says something like add connection string to app.config.

All your stuff the connection depends on then appears in that particular project's own config.

These aren't the configs you're looking for.

Or at least not the config the exe will look in when your dll is loaded and runs in it's context.

Simplest fix:

Copy all the connection stuff out your project config into the main solution's config.